# Overlapping subplot-title since update of Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I recently had to re-install my OS and decided to switch to Python3. With it came updates of my IDE PyCharm and presumably also an update of Matplotlib.

Running a script that worked perfectly fine before, now gives me ugly results with overlapping titles of my subplots.

This is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(20,4))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True, sharey=True, sharex=True)
axes[-1, 0].set_xlabel('.\n', color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
axes[-1, 0].set_ylabel('.\n', color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
for s_plot, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.scatter(x=range(20), y=z[:,s_plot])

fig.suptitle("The Title\nSecond Line\n", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

This produces:
[image]

I tried setting `constrained_layout` to `False` and also experimented with `subplots_adjust`, but it does not change the layout of my plots.

I am currently using matplotlib 3.0.2. Was there a major change I have missed? I am puzzled about how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Using matplotlib 3.0.2 the plot would look as follows

**Using `constrained_layout=True`**
[image]

**Using `constrained_layout=False`**
[image]

Both outcomes are expected. In the case of `constrained_layout` being used the title *appears* off-center, because there is more space to the left of the subplots being used by labels than on the right.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Any idea why I am getting the result shown in the question?

Comment: Can you run the code outside of pycharm? Would it produce the same?

Comment: Good point. I saved the plot using `plt.savefig` and everything looks fine. It seems to be a problem with the PyCharm update, not the matplotlib update. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: Mhh, it seems PyCharm is often the cause for trouble with matplotlib. They use their own backend by default. So maybe that causes hickups.

Answer (score 0):

I also think this is a problem with pycharm. So for example when I run the code in this standard matplotlib script:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html

I get this image where the title and suptitle overlap:
[image]

However the title and suptitle do not overlap when saved to png.

I have raised an issue with pycharm to hopefully get this resolved:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42545

In the meantime I suggest splitting your editor screen to display the .png file which you can refresh using CTRL+ALT+Y every time you run the code.